# Join two strings together without being added in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: string, join, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How can I join two strings (both are numbers) together without having them added together? For example:

```
@output = 2567 + 18
```

**What I Don't Want:**

The result returns "2585" (it has added the two numbers together mathematically).

**What I Do Want:**

The result returns "256718". As you can see, this time the two numbers have been joined together, not added.

## A Real Example:

```
Profile.create(:permalink => 2585 && User.last.id)
```

When I run that line from my model - the row titled "permalink" simply gets the last created user ID, and "2585" isn't joined in front of it. Also, if I used the "+" method **instead of** "&&" like in the first example, the two numbers are added together mathematically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert both values to strings. The first with a string literal and the second with an explicit conversion using the `to_s` method.

```
Profile.create(:permalink => "2585" + User.last.id.to_s)
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm, Andrew. Thanks a lot. What exactly does `.to_s` do in this situation though, I don't understand?

Comment: It converts the Fixnum returned by `User.last.id` (in your example `18`) into its string representation. You can see the source/docs here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s

Answer (score 3):

I think you can try to convert the **number**s into **string** first.
For your example

```
@output = "2567" + "18"
```

or

```
@output = (2567.to_s) + (18.to_s)
```

will both get 256718, which is what you want.

Comment: Yeah, that's what Andrew Hubbs suggested in his answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much Ruby, but I would think that using a string-literal would tell the interpreter what you're wanting to do.  Try:

```
Profile.create(:permalink => "2585" + User.last.id)
```

Comment: Hey Andrew, thanks for getting back to me. Nope, no luck there with that suggestion - rails returns an error which states that it `can't convert Fixnum into String`.

Comment: This would work in Perl,  but Ruby is strongly typed so you need to explicitly convert types. However,  Ruby string interpolation converts types to String automatically. ‛:permalink => "2585#{User.last.id}"‛